# css, chrome, работа с консолью

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, консоль

Добрый вечер, Как определить у какого файла приоритет больше чем у твоих стилей. Т.е. если взглянуть на консоль, то кто отключает мои стили с background ом

Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вкладке styles показан актуальный порядок. Ваш фон перекрывается фоном класса `.category-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Приоритет выстраивается по порядку подключения css файлов. Подключеный последним наиболее приоритетный. А какой именно перебивает - наведите на название файла которое находится в правой части каждого правила сss и увидите полный путь к файлу.

Comment: стоит отметить, что на приоритет так же влияет указатель. обращение к тегам/классам/идентификаторам (и т.д.) так же имеют приоритеты в определении стилей, независимо выше ли он был объявлен или ниже.

Answer (score 0):

еще не только последовательностю подключения стилей, но и переопределением сойства. Тоесть вы сначала написали:
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
background-color: #333;

а потом, выше по каскадности в последнем подключеном файле переопределили все эти свойства одним - background: url("../images/1.jpg");

Вот статья [ссылка](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/) чтобы понять более наглядно.

Comment: То что я переопределил на картинку - это понятно. Потому, что если картинка будет отсутствовать или удалиться из сервера, то вместо него background зальется монохромом. 
Но проблема в том, что мой style.css подключен последним в <head>, однаком каким-то образом его что-то переопределяет

Comment: @KamilNHOT свойство `background` является короткой записью всех тех свойств, которые в инспекторе сейчас выглядят зачеркнутыми. если всё, что вам необходимо добавить, это картинка, то воспользуйтесь свойством `background-image: url()`.

Comment: Понял, что имеете ввиду. Спасибо !

Comment: но тогда, если файл подключен последним, но свойства его переопределяются, то нужно смотреть на вес селектора, для которого вы задаете стиля